# Use JSON data in another JSP page

Tags: java, json, jsp

I'm sending information through two JSP pages, but I couldn't print the info in the second page.

```
function sendSuccess (dir) {
    console.log(jdata);
    $.ajax({
        url: dir,
        type: "POST",
        data: jdata,            
        contentType: "application/json"
    })
    .done(function( response ) {
        $("#energyQuote").hide();
        $("#success_msg").html(response).fadeIn('slow'); 
    });     
}
```

In Google Chrome with the `console.log` statement I get this:

```
Object {name_id: "tre", tlfono: "435", email_id: "dg@dfss.ghj", consumo_hm: "324", numFront_id0: "324"…}consumo_hm: "324"cotizac_id: "24"email_id: "dg@dfss.ghj"kva_id0: "324"name_id: "tre"numFront_id0: "324"tlfono: "435"__proto__: Object
```

In the second JSP I use to print:

```
<%= request.getAttribute("name_id") %>
<%= request.getParameter("name_id") %>
<%= ics.GetVar("jdata.type_Identify") %>
```

But always I get null values.

Comment: first you need to parse the json

Comment: I you didn't use JSON, the servlet container would give you the parameters automatically, but I suppose you have a good reason to do so. Just read the body and parse it but do not rely on any help from JSP machinery since **you** choosed not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

In your second JSP,write below line of code

```
BufferedReader bf = request.getReader();
 StringBuffer sbf = new StringBuffer();
 String line = null;
 while((line = bf.readLine())!=null){
    sbf.append(line);
 }
```

Now you can use the data in sbf object as you want.

Comment: That will write all the data from the request which includes headers and such.

Comment: Thx. It throws an error here: `request.getReader();`